# What code can make the lower bounds of turtle and patch variables stay above zero?

Tags: netlogo, bioinformatics, modeling, agent, agent-based-modeling

[Egg number variable goes into minus figures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oM4fy.jpg)

Turtles-own and patches-own variables continue to dive into minus numbers despite the codes attempted below.

Attempt 1: This code placed immediately after defining Patches-own and Turtles-own variables.

```
to rescale-egg-number
  let _newmin 0
  let _newmax 1000
  let _newrange (_newmax - _newmin)
  ask turtles [
  ]
end
```

Attempt 2: This code incorporated into the "To go" command

```
if egg-number <= -1
    [set egg-number  0
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show how/where/when `turtles-own` and `patches-own` variables are being modified. You might just find the mistake yourself while improving your question.

Answer (score 1):

Placing the same line of code below instead of above the parameter variables works.

```
if temperature >= 20
[set egg-number (egg-number - 50)
set larvae-number (larvae-number + 50)
if temperature >= 25
[set egg-number (egg-number - 70)
set larvae-number (larvae-number + 70)
        

if egg-number <= 0
[set egg-number  0
if larvae-number <= 0
[set larvae-number 0
```